# Sveltekit - Form action - fail doesn't work

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I try to implement a form action, but I have some trouble with error handling/validation (nameMissing and emailMissing values would be used for validation)

```js
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const actions = {
  default: async ({ request }) => {
    const form = await request.formData();
    const name = form.get('name');
    const email = form.get('email');
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    if(!name) {
      return fail(400, {nameMissing: true })
    }

    if(!email) {
      return fail(400, {emailMissing: true })
    }

    return { success: true }

  },
};
```

It seems to me, the fail import is not successful, because if I use a console.log in my if, it works.
Thanks

Comment: What is your page UI code? How do you determine it to "not work"?